# Finding GDAL Build Format List?

Tags: gdal, ogr, documentation

I am building GDAL from source to limit the list of supported drivers however I cannot find a definitive list of formats and their appropriate shorthand names to use in my ./configure list to set them to without

I have found https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithMinimizedDrivers but I don't think this is the full list.

In release 3 there is now a version to build without all the optional drivers using `--disable-all-optional-drivers` but even using this still gives me a number of drivers for example MapInfo and TopoJSON that i do not want to include.

Comment: If `disable-all-optional-drivers` still builds TopoJSON that is not reported as a driver that can't be disabled then it is perhaps a bug. I would ask that from the gdal-dev mailing list. MapInfo driver you can't clearly avoid.

Comment: I noticed that you asked already, and that you have not noticed that "mitab" stands for the MapInfo formats https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mitab.html.

Answer (score 2):

Wiki page does not seem to be up-to-date but you can consider fixing it, it is wiki.

This GitHub issue is no new that I guess the information is correct https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/1250

> OGR drivers that cannot be disabled and will always be built: **generic
>   geojson kml mem mitab vrt**
>
> GDAL drivers that cannot be disabled and will always be built: **derived
>   gtiff hfa mem raw vrt**

Afterward at least "raw" driver has been changed so that it can be disabled as well. Mitab was considered to be refactored as well but is perhaps still in the queue.

Comment: That GitHub issue is where i found that I could disable many of the optional ones. However what I am after is a full list of driver name eg PostgreSQL and then its name to be used in the configure list, eg --without-pg.

Comment: Have a look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/gdal/configure and lines with "enabled by default", like `--disable-driver-plmosaic
                          disable plmosaic format support (enabled by default,
                          requires curl)`. Disable seems to use unofficial names for some drivers `--disable-driver-shape`.